# (solved) Kubuntu 16.04: Tearing in SMPlayer despite VDPAU

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, tearing, smplayer, vdpau

In Kubuntu 16.04, I installed the nvidia binary driver version 384.69 using ["Graphics Drivers" team's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). I also tried version 381.22, the current official release, with the same result. I setup SMplayer 15.11.0 to use VDPAU and made sure it's really using VDPAU by starting h.264 video playback and looking at the command that plays the video. Here's an example:

```
/usr/bin/mpv --no-config --no-quiet --terminal --no-msg-color --input-file=/dev/stdin --no-fs --vd-lavc-threads=12 --hwdec=vdpau --sub-auto=fuzzy --vo=vdpau --ao=alsa:device=[hw:2,0] --no-input-default-bindings --input-x11-keyboard=no --no-input-cursor --cursor-autohide=no --no-keepaspect --wid=100664033 --monitorpixelaspect=1 --osd-scale=1 --sub-ass --embeddedfonts --ass-line-spacing=0 --sub-scale=1 --sub-text-font=Fira Sans --sub-text-color=#ffffff --sub-text-shadow-color=#000000 --sub-text-border-color=#000000 --sub-text-border-size=2.5 --sub-text-shadow-offset=5 --ass-force-style=PlayResX=512,PlayResY=320,Name=Default,Fontname=Fira Sans,Fontsize=20,PrimaryColour=&H00ffffff,BackColour=&H00000000,OutlineColour=&H00000000,Bold=0,Italic=0,Alignment=2,BorderStyle=1,Outline=1,Shadow=2,MarginL=20,MarginR=20,MarginV=8 --sub-codepage=utf8:ISO-8859-1 --vid=1 --aid=1 --sub-pos=100 --volume=50 --cache=2048 --osd-level=0 --audio-channels=2 --af-add=scaletempo --af-add=equalizer=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 --softvol=yes --softvol-max=100 --ytdl=no --term-playing-msg=MPV_VERSION=${=mpv-version:} INFO_VIDEO_WIDTH=${=width} INFO_VIDEO_HEIGHT=${=height} INFO_VIDEO_ASPECT=${=video-aspect} INFO_VIDEO_FPS=${=fps} INFO_VIDEO_FORMAT=${=video-format} INFO_VIDEO_CODEC=${=video-codec} INFO_AUDIO_FORMAT=${=audio-codec-name:${=audio-format}} INFO_AUDIO_CODEC=${=audio-codec} INFO_AUDIO_RATE=${=audio-params/samplerate:${=audio-samplerate}} INFO_AUDIO_NCH=${=audio-params/channel-count:${=audio-channels}} INFO_LENGTH=${=duration:${=length}} INFO_DEMUXER=${=demuxer} INFO_TITLES=${=disc-titles} INFO_CHAPTERS=${=chapters} INFO_TRACKS_COUNT=${=track-list/count} METADATA_TITLE=${metadata/by-key/title:} METADATA_ARTIST=${metadata/by-key/artist:} METADATA_ALBUM=${metadata/by-key/album:} METADATA_GENRE=${metadata/by-key/genre:} METADATA_DATE=${metadata/by-key/date:} METADATA_TRACK=${metadata/by-key/track:} METADATA_COPYRIGHT=${metadata/by-key/copyright:} INFO_MEDIA_TITLE=${=media-title:}  --term-status-msg=STATUS: ${=time-pos} / ${=duration:${=length:0}} P: ${=pause} B: ${=paused-for-cache} I: ${=core-idle} /home/user/video.mkv
```

I experimented with the number of threads (12 in the above example), enabling and disabling the loop filter, direct rendering and other options, all without much effect.

My graphics card is an nvidia geforce 1070. I'm able to watch the same video files I tested with an old computer with a 9 year old nvidia 9600 GT graphics card without any tearing whatsoever, so I assume it should be possible to solve this problem.

In case that is helpful, here's the output of vdpauinfo:

```
display: :0   screen: 0
API version: 1
Information string: NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  384.69  Wed Aug 16 19:38:45 PDT 2017

Video surface:

name   width height types
-------------------------------------------
420     8192  8192  NV12 YV12 
422     8192  8192  UYVY YUYV 

Decoder capabilities:

name                        level macbs width height
----------------------------------------------------
MPEG1                           0 65536  4096  4096
MPEG2_SIMPLE                    3 65536  4096  4096
MPEG2_MAIN                      3 65536  4096  4096
H264_BASELINE                  41 65536  4096  4096
H264_MAIN                      41 65536  4096  4096
H264_HIGH                      41 65536  4096  4096
VC1_SIMPLE                      1  8190  2048  2048
VC1_MAIN                        2  8190  2048  2048
VC1_ADVANCED                    4  8190  2048  2048
MPEG4_PART2_SP                  3  8192  2048  2048
MPEG4_PART2_ASP                 5  8192  2048  2048
DIVX4_QMOBILE                   0  8192  2048  2048
DIVX4_MOBILE                    0  8192  2048  2048
DIVX4_HOME_THEATER              0  8192  2048  2048
DIVX4_HD_1080P                  0  8192  2048  2048
DIVX5_QMOBILE                   0  8192  2048  2048
DIVX5_MOBILE                    0  8192  2048  2048
DIVX5_HOME_THEATER              0  8192  2048  2048
DIVX5_HD_1080P                  0  8192  2048  2048
H264_CONSTRAINED_BASELINE      41 65536  4096  4096
H264_EXTENDED                  41 65536  4096  4096
H264_PROGRESSIVE_HIGH          41 65536  4096  4096
H264_CONSTRAINED_HIGH          41 65536  4096  4096
H264_HIGH_444_PREDICTIVE       41 65536  4096  4096
HEVC_MAIN                      153 262144  8192  8192
HEVC_MAIN_10                   --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN_STILL                --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN_12                   --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN_444                  --- not supported ---

Output surface:

name              width height nat types
----------------------------------------------------
B8G8R8A8         32768 32768    y  Y8U8V8A8 V8U8Y8A8 A4I4 I4A4 A8I8 I8A8 
R10G10B10A2      32768 32768    y  Y8U8V8A8 V8U8Y8A8 A4I4 I4A4 A8I8 I8A8 

Bitmap surface:

name              width height
------------------------------
B8G8R8A8         32768 32768
R8G8B8A8         32768 32768
R10G10B10A2      32768 32768
B10G10R10A2      32768 32768
A8               32768 32768

Video mixer:

feature name                    sup
------------------------------------
DEINTERLACE_TEMPORAL             y
DEINTERLACE_TEMPORAL_SPATIAL     y
INVERSE_TELECINE                 y
NOISE_REDUCTION                  y
SHARPNESS                        y
LUMA_KEY                         y
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L1        y
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L2        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L3        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L4        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L5        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L6        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L7        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L8        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L9        -

parameter name                  sup      min      max
-----------------------------------------------------
VIDEO_SURFACE_WIDTH              y         1     8192
VIDEO_SURFACE_HEIGHT             y         1     8192
CHROMA_TYPE                      y  
LAYERS                           y         0        4

attribute name                  sup      min      max
-----------------------------------------------------
BACKGROUND_COLOR                 y  
CSC_MATRIX                       y  
NOISE_REDUCTION_LEVEL            y      0.00     1.00
SHARPNESS_LEVEL                  y     -1.00     1.00
LUMA_KEY_MIN_LUMA                y  
LUMA_KEY_MAX_LUMA                y
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Helping myself: The following command seems to solve the problem.

```
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="HMDI-0: nvidia-auto-select { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

Now I "only" need to find a way to have it executed automatically. To make the change permanent, I found out that it is suggested to add the following lines to /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
Section "Screen"
    …
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select {ForceCompositionPipeline = On }"
EndSection
```

My problem is: On this version of Kubuntu, there is no such file anymore. I tried to add a new section to
        usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf/nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf
but without success. So my current question is: Where shall I put that line?

**Edit:** Well, I consider this problem solved: I created a bash script with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                            
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }"
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DP-1: nvidia-auto-select { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }"  
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DP-2: nvidia-auto-select { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

I adjusted my system settings to run the script each time I login. It effectively works against tearing artifacts on HDMI and display ports. In case anyone is plagued by the same problem, you can find out the name of the appropriate port with

```
xrandr | grep " connect"
```